# How do I install selenium for Atom IDE?

Tags: selenium, atom-editor

When I try my code in the Atom IDE.

```
from selenium import webdriver

br = webdriver.Firefox()
br.get('https://www.facebook.com/login/')
email = br.find_element_by_id('email')
email.send_keys('7021038678')
pas = br.find_element_by_id('pass')

pas.send_keys('welcome')
pas.submit()
```

I get an error saying this:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckdriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I did pip install --user selenium in the console command in Atom. I've looked at other posts about this, however I'm not sure how I would fix it with the Atom IDE since I'm using Atom for Python instead of the Python IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is an issue with Selenium. You should read what the error says: 'geckdriver.exe' which is a FireFox webdriver selenium uses to run tests.

All you need to do is install geckodriver and make a reference to the file directory in your PATH in your systems environment variables

Comment: No problem. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass the path to Geckodriver during initializatin

```
br = webdriver.Firefox('@your_browser_path')
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your answer. Also use code blocks for your code for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

It will try to install GeckoDriver for Firefox every time.

Note: First you have to install the package using:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```